# Jenkinsfile with failsafe reports

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a jenkinsfile that generates the maven surefire reports and also uses failsafe for integration tests.

I can archive the test repots from surefire and see them via the link in Jenkins, and I would like to do the same for failsafe.  The failsafe plugin is not generating reports at all, much less making them available via Jenkins.

How do I do that?  Here's my jenkinsfile:

```
node {
   stage 'Checkout'
   git credentialsId: 'mike', url: 'mike@lhost:/repo'
   def mvnHome = tool 'M3'

   stage 'Build'
   sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean package verify"
   step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])

   stage 'SonarQube'
   sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.3.70:9000 sonar:sonar"

}
```

Here is the POM for failsave:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Again, I see the tests run and pass but I don't see reports or how to make Jenkins archive and display them.

Comment: if you run mvn locally and then run `ls **/target/failsafe-reports/*.xml`, you're saying nothing shows up? so the problem is not related to jenkins?

Comment: The call `mvn clean package verify` is simply wrong...use `mvn clean verify` cause package is part of the lifecycle...

Answer (score 0):

You only include reports from surefire:

`step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])`

Maybe this helps:

`step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml'])`